# AngularJs - ngRepeat with a filter that returns a new object

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to apply a transformation to the objects in my filter, which results in an array of new objects being returned.  This is because I want to filter the objects AFTER the transformation is applied and display the results of the transformation.  However, I end up with an infinite digest because the objects I display are different than the objects I put in (when comparing their `$$ids`).  My thoughts to solve this are the following:

1. Use a tracking expression like `track by item.id` and assign the original objects' `ids` to each of the transformed objects.  While all my objects currently do have an `id`, this seems like a bad idea because it makes the filter much less general- the original objects must have an `id`, the transformation must not set an `id` (as it will be overwritten), etc.
2. Assign the original object's `$$id` to the transformed objects.  This seems hackish, based on my understanding `$$id` is supposed to be read only.
3. Return a subset of the original objects based on the result of the transformation's filtering.  This may cause performance issues as the transformation needs to be applied in both the filter and the display expression, AND I have to loop back through the transformed / filtered items to select the right original ones to return.

Here is the filter:

```
listModule.filter('ui.filter.transformFilter',
                 ['$filter',
                  '$id',
                   function($filter, $id)
  {
    var Filter = $filter('filter');
    return function(objects, transformer, expression) {
      // precondition- we need a list of objects
      if (!_.isArray(objects)) {
        return objects;
      }

      var transformed = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        transformed[i] = transformer(objects[i]);
      }

      return filtered = Filter(transformed, expression);
    }                  
  }]
);
```

And here is how I am trying to use it:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="item in list.items | ui.filter.transformFilter:list.transformerFunction:list.search" ng-click="list.select({'item': item})" class="list-item">
    <td ng-repeat="label in list.labels" ng-bind-html="item[label.key]"></td>
  </tr>
```

Oh, and ideally `ngClick` returns the original object, but I can always wrap a function around it to look that up.

Comment: I think I know the solution :) I'm working on it.

Comment: Do you have some sample data for `list.labels`?

Answer (score 7):

One solution to this problem where you have an idempotent function that Angular, due to object IDs, thinks is not idempotent (and thus causes the $digest loop issue as you noted) is to **use lo-dash/underscore's [`_.memoize`](http://lodash.com/docs#memoize) to cache your function's results**.

This will guarantee that for any given cache key your filter will always return a completely identical object (including `$$id`).  This way you don't have to play games with `$$id` and you get the **performance benefit of not having to recompute the filter results** on each $digest loop.

Here's how you could cache your filter's results:

```
return _.memoize(function(objects, transformer, expression) { ... },
                 function(objects,transformer,expression){ 
                    return objects +transformer.name + expression;
                  });
```

One important note for your situation is that by default `_.memoize` uses the first function parameter (`objects` in this case) as the cache key.  Since your filter likely produces different results given different transformer functions and expressions I've added the optional second parameter- a hash function that uses `objects`,`expression`, and the name of the `transformer` function to produce a cache key.

Here's a simplified version of your code using this:  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hK6tg/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Angular uses [`angular.equals`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.equals) to detect scope changes. Tracking expressions are used to match array items with DOM elements, so that when you filter or reorder the array, Angular will only show, hide or reorder some elements, instead of rebuilding entire subtree.

Have a look at this simple example: **http://jsfiddle.net/Nb8mX/**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

    $scope.transform = function(item) {
        item.abc *= 2;
        return true;
    };

    $scope.data = [
        {abc: 123, def: 1},
        {abc: 456, def: 2},
        {abc: 789, def: 3}
    ];

}
```

Modifying the item by a filter causes infinite digest loop regardless of `track by`, while doing the same inside `ng-init` works without issues:

```
<ul ng-app="blah" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter : transform">{{ item.abc }}</li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter : transform track by item.def">{{ item.abc }}</li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data" ng-init="transform(item)">{{ item.abc }}</li>
</ul>
```

This shows that you could write a directive instead of a filter.

If anyone knows of a better solution I'll be glad to learn it too.