# AngularJS ordered repeat on key-value associative array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sql-order-by, repeat

I have a problem rendering an associative array with non-object values with AngularJS. Data like the following can be sorted using toArray:

```
{ key1: { value : data }, key2 : { value : data } }
```

But if you want to sort an associative array which does not contain objects like the following, the digest cycle will keep running until you get [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10)

```
{ key1: { value : data }, key2 : { value : data } }
```

1. In the below code, the first sample shows the unsorted version (default).
2. The second one can sort, but the keys are lost (only $index being available).
3. The third one uses the toArray filter from http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-toArrayFilter and manages to sort the array and keep the keys, but it throws an error because the digest keeps running.
4. The last one is like the 3rd one but sorts an associative array containing objects (which will not throw any error).

```js
angular.module('app', ['angular-toArrayFilter']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter/master/toArrayFilter.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-init="items = {a:'A', d:'D', c:'C', b:'B'}; items2 = {a:{value:'A'}, d:{value:'D'}, c:{value:'C'}, b:{value:'B'}}; ">
  Normal iteration (unsorted - depending on browser)
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in items">{{ key }} = {{ value }}</li>
  </ul>
  Sorted iteration (sorted, but no access to key)
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy track by item">{{ $index }} = {{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  Sorted iteration (works, but throws error)
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | toArray | orderBy : '$key' track by item.$key">{{ item.$key }} = {{ item.$value }}</li>
  </ul>
  Sorted iteration with objects (works only with objects)
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items2 | toArray | orderBy : '$key' track by item.$key">{{ item.$key }} = {{ item.value }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I know solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446557/2628232 using underscore's `memoize`, but I want to avoid doing this. Depending on the answers here, I think this should be reported as an issue to AngularJS so a proper solution could be built in.